# Error when publishing my site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I created a site and when I try to publish it, I receive a error:

> Unable to remove directory "obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir". The folder is not empty

The build and rebuild occurs ok, but not the publish.

I can't find the folder to clear it. How can I fix that error?

Comment: Try to use Build > Clean Solution and then Build > Rebuild Solution

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not work. The build occurs ok, but not the publish

Comment: The files are probably still being used and this happens sometimes. What Camilo suggested should be a fix else you could try to also just do a restart of visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to the local files inside Your `solution/project`. Anything in the "obj" folder is used by Visual Studio, during building the project/putting code together. It seems that at some moment, VS is trying to delete these files, but some process is still running and the VS is not allowed to delete it.

As suggested from the comments, **restarting Visual Studio** and/or **Cleaning the Solution** works most of the time.

However from time to time, some other processes can touch these folder structure. In such case You should find this process/application and stop it. Or simply restart the computer (it stops all actually running processes), on fresh start You should be allowed to **run the publish action** as before.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the (TemporaryGeneratedFile) from your \obj\Release
you will find three files after delete it try to publish and till us what happened

Answer (score 0):

delete all files in obj/debug , obj/release and delete bin/app.publish

- then rebuild project

--that works for me

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem: Delete everything inside the OBJ folder inside your project manually.